# Android Parse ampersand in XML

Tags: android, xml, saxparser, ampersand

In an app I'm developing I get an XML string that I have to parse in the app to properly store the data in the local database. The problem is that when a field in the XML has an ampersand like a trademark ("Pans&Company" e.g.), the parser crashes with the next error: *ParseException: undefined entity*.

How I can handle this situations easily with SAXParser? This is driving me crazy, I read a ton of solutions but any is useful for me.

Comment: check this out xmlparser http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: You can use `\u0026` instead of `&`

Comment: Ampersand must be quoted in XML as `&amp;`. Similarly, `<` should be `&lt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't handle invalid XML with an XML parser - you have to deal with it at source. Find out who is generating this incorrect XML and get them to fix their code. An ampersand must be written as `&amp;`.